# php loop over multidimentional array woocommerce REST API

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the PHP library for the woocommerce REST API. I need to gather information regarding orders. I have tried many different ways of looping over the array that is returned from the get->orders function but cannot retrieve all the information I need.

Here is a var_dump of the returned array:

[image]

I can return the order number, order total, total items and date/time order created.

But I want to list out the items from the order, these items are in the 'line_items' array within the main array. The image doesn't show the items but it would be the same method to return the customer information from the 'billing_address' array again within the main array.

The current loop I have is this:

```
$orders = $connect->orders->get();



            foreach( $orders as $order ) {
              foreach( $order as $value ) {

                    echo $value["id"];
                    echo $value["total"];
                    echo $value["total_line_items_quantity"];
                    echo $value["status"];

              }
            }
```

Appreciate any help.

Note: here is the woocommerce REST API: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#view-list-of-orders

In response to Mihia

```
[shipping_address] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => Chris
                        [last_name] => data
                        [company] => 
                        [address_1] => data
                        [address_2] => 
                        [city] => data
                        [state] => 
                        [postcode] => data
                        [country] => GB
                    )

                [note] => 
                [customer_ip] => IP address
                [customer_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
                [customer_id] => 1
                [view_order_url] => data                
[line_items] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 4
                                [subtotal] => 0.00
                                [subtotal_tax] => 0.00
                                [total] => 0.00
                                [total_tax] => 0.00
                                [price] => 0.00
                                [quantity] => 1
                                [tax_class] => 
                                [name] => Chips (Regular)
                                [product_id] => 8
                                [sku] => sku_8
                                [meta] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 5
                                [subtotal] => 0.00
                                [subtotal_tax] => 0.00
                                [total] => 0.00
                                [total_tax] => 0.00
                                [price] => 0.00
                                [quantity] => 1
                                [tax_class] => 
                                [name] => Cod (Regular)
                                [product_id] => 14
                                [sku] => cod01
                                [meta] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [shipping_lines] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [tax_lines] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fee_lines] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [coupon_lines] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [customer] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [created_at] => 2015-07-29T16:12:13Z
                        [email] => data
                        [first_name] => 
                        [last_name] => 
                        [username] => data
                        [role] => data
                        [last_order_id] => 22
                        [last_order_date] => 2015-07-30T14:01:54Z
                        [orders_count] => 5
                        [total_spent] => 7.96
                        [avatar_url] => http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=96
                        [billing_address] => Array
                            (
                                [first_name] => Chris
                                [last_name] => data
                                [company] => 
                                [address_1] => data
                                [address_2] => 
                                [city] => data
                                [state] => 
                                [postcode] => data
                                [country] => GB
                                [email] => data
                                [phone] => data
                            )

                        [shipping_address] => Array
                            (
                                [first_name] => Chris
                                [last_name] => data
                                [company] => 
                                [address_1] => data
                                [address_2] => 
                                [city] => data
                                [state] => 
                                [postcode] => data
                                [country] => data
                            )

                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 13
                [order_number] => 13
                [created_at] => 2015-07-29T17:04:02Z
                [updated_at] => 2015-07-29T17:04:02Z
                [completed_at] => 2015-07-29T16:04:02Z
                [status] => processing
                [currency] => GBP
                [total] => 0.00
                [subtotal] => 0.00
                [total_line_items_quantity] => 1
                [total_tax] => 0.00
                [total_shipping] => 0.00
                [cart_tax] => 0.00
                [shipping_tax] => 0.00
                [total_discount] => 0.00
                [shipping_methods] => 
                [payment_details] => Array
                    (
                        [method_id] => 
                        [method_title] => 
                        [paid] => 1
                    )

                [billing_address] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => Chris
                        [last_name] => data
                        [company] => 
                        [address_1] => data
                        [address_2] => 
                        [city] => data
                        [state] => 
                        [postcode] => data
                        [country] => GB
                        [email] => data
                        [phone] => data
                    )

                [shipping_address] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => Chris
                        [last_name] => data
                        [company] => 
                        [address_1] => data
                        [address_2] => 
                        [city] => data
                        [state] => 
                        [postcode] => data
                        [country] => GB
                    )

                [note] => 
                [customer_ip] => data
                [customer_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
                [customer_id] => 1
                [view_order_url] => data                
[line_items] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [subtotal] => 0.00
                                [subtotal_tax] => 0.00
                                [total] => 0.00
                                [total_tax] => 0.00
                                [price] => 0.00
                                [quantity] => 1
                                [tax_class] => 
                                [name] => Chips (Regular)
                                [product_id] => 8
                                [sku] => sku_8
                                [meta] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [shipping_lines] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [tax_lines] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fee_lines] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [coupon_lines] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [customer] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [created_at] => 2015-07-29T16:12:13Z
                        [email] => data
                        [first_name] => 
                        [last_name] => 
                        [username] => data
                        [role] => data
                        [last_order_id] => 22
                        [last_order_date] => 2015-07-30T14:01:54Z
                        [orders_count] => 5
                        [total_spent] => 7.96
                        [avatar_url] => http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=96
                        [billing_address] => Array
                            (
                                [first_name] => Chris
                                [last_name] => data
                                [company] => 
                                [address_1] => data
                                [address_2] => 
                                [city] => data
                                [state] => 
                                [postcode] => data
                                [country] => GB
                                [email] => data
                                [phone] => data
                            )

                        [shipping_address] => Array
                            (
                                [first_name] => Chris
                                [last_name] => data
                                [company] => 
                                [address_1] => data
                                [address_2] => 
                                [city] => data
                                [state] => 
                                [postcode] => data
                                [country] => GB
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Comment: Hard to make sense of that array but use `foreach( $orders as $key=>$value) {
              foreach( $value as $vkey=>$vvalue) {` and you should be able to parse any depth of that array

Comment: Please see the edited response.

Comment: When using  a loop a like you mentioned and targeting a specific key for example ['order'] I get an illegal string offset error.

I can have the results returned as json, the problem I have there is I have no idea how to then output that json data

Comment: you have to insert in there an is_array check

Comment: Anyway I try and write this loop I either get an array to string conversion error or an illegal offset error

This is one of example of how I have tried to echo the order number:

 foreach($orders as $key=>$value) { 
                foreach( $value as $vkey=>$vvalue) {
                    if(is_array($value)) {
                        echo $vkey['order']['order_number'] . $vvalue;   
                    }
                    
                }
            }

I do appreciate your help!

Comment: You probably can do it but I\`m too lazy to try and digest that huge ass array.Look into some array functions maybe array_slice or use isset and is_array checks everywhere.Or start simple with just those foreach and `echo  $key.'</br>';` and so on; start small,see what comes up,maybe fill another array with what you need.

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into it.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming that `$orders` holds the array in your image, your line items would be available as follows:

```
$line_items = $orders['order']['line_items'];
```

I don't see any use case for using `foreach` loop or similar iterative traversal of `$orders` as you have a very specifically-structured set of nested associative arrays.

For example `foreach( $orders as $order )` makes no sense as the first iteration would give you the order information, whereas the second iteration would go into the http request information.  These are not like data structures so this sort of loop makes no sense.

Similarly, looping `$order` makes no sense either.  Even assuming we are on the first iteration of the outer loop, which gives if the order information, this inner loop would simply loop over the values of the array with keys not even being looked at, so you would get values like:

```
21
21
'2015-07-30T13:09:31Z'
...
Array()
...
```

You would eventually encounter your `line_items` array, but you wouldn't know when you did, because you have lost reference to the key associated with the value.

Comment: HI Mike, I understand where you are coming from. Is there a way that I can simply extract information from this array then? Basically I need to list out the orders but I only want specific information.

Comment: I can have the results returned as json, the problem I have there is I have no idea how to then output that json data

Comment: That's a completely different question @ChrisHinds. Your question related to looping over a multidimensional array to create variables. Mike answered your question.

Comment: @ChrisHinds The code one-liner I provided should get you access to the line_items array unless your actual structure differs from what is in your image.  If you are looking for more fundamental knowledge around how to work with numerically-indexed and associative arrays in PHP, then you really should refer to the PHP documentation.  The way you output the data you want to output is to first understand where in the data structure your data lies, and then output an appropriate representation the data to meet your needs.

Comment: @Mike HI Mike, again thanks for your help.

I have just realied why your code line wasn't working for me before. I had to specify an order id in the function when getting the orders. Apparently it doesn't want me to simply get a list of orders. But this is another step closer :)

And yes I agree I need to understand the structure of the array a little more. Time for some reading!